Проблема с шифрованием точки доступа NetworkManager
Всем привет. Создал с помощью nmtui точку доступа, тип защиты выбрал "WPA и WPA2 Personal" но не могу подключиться. На смартфоне в свойствах этой точки доступа указано тип защиты "WPA2/WPA3", после ввода пароля ничего не происходит (подключался из-под Android и Windows), пароль вводил 100% верный. Если создать точку доступа без защиты то все прекрасно работает. В логах NetworkManager ничего подозрительного нет.
Параметры подключения:
root@debian:~# nmcli con show ap-wlp2s0
connection.id:                          ap-wlp2s0
connection.uuid:                        90ba40d7-fe10-470e-a4fd-cd89357d1c19
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.type:                        802-11-wireless
connection.interface-name:              wlp2s0
connection.autoconnect:                 да
connection.autoconnect-priority:        0
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (default)
connection.multi-connect:               0 (default)
connection.auth-retries:                -1
connection.timestamp:                   1721673202
connection.read-only:                   нет
connection.permissions:                 --
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:                 --
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     неизвестно
connection.lldp:                        default
connection.mdns:                        -1 (default)
connection.llmnr:                       -1 (default)
connection.dns-over-tls:                -1 (default)
connection.mptcp-flags:                 0x0 (default)
connection.wait-device-timeout:         -1
connection.wait-activation-delay:       -1
802-11-wireless.ssid:                   Test_ap
802-11-wireless.mode:                   ap
802-11-wireless.band:                   --
802-11-wireless.channel:                0
802-11-wireless.bssid:                  --
802-11-wireless.rate:                   0
802-11-wireless.tx-power:               0
802-11-wireless.mac-address:            --
802-11-wireless.cloned-mac-address:     --
802-11-wireless.generate-mac-address-mask:--
802-11-wireless.mac-address-blacklist:  --
802-11-wireless.mac-address-randomization:default
802-11-wireless.mtu:                    автоматически
802-11-wireless.seen-bssids:            C8:8A:D8:45:CB:0E
802-11-wireless.hidden:                 нет
802-11-wireless.powersave:              0 (default)
802-11-wireless.wake-on-wlan:           0x1 (default)
802-11-wireless.ap-isolation:           -1 (default)
802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt:      wpa-psk
802-11-wireless-security.wep-tx-keyidx: 0
802-11-wireless-security.auth-alg:      --
802-11-wireless-security.proto:         --
802-11-wireless-security.pairwise:      --
802-11-wireless-security.group:         --
802-11-wireless-security.pmf:           0 (default)
802-11-wireless-security.leap-username: --
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key0:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key1:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key2:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key3:      <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key-flags: 0 (нет)
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key-type:  unknown
802-11-wireless-security.psk:           <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.psk-flags:     0 (нет)
802-11-wireless-security.leap-password: <hidden>
802-11-wireless-security.leap-password-flags:0 (нет)
802-11-wireless-security.wps-method:    0x0 (default)
802-11-wireless-security.fils:          0 (default)
ipv4.method:                            manual
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       --
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         192.168.1.1/24
ipv4.gateway:                           192.168.1.1
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.routing-rules:                     --
ipv4.replace-local-rule:                -1 (default)
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                нет
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   нет
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                да
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv4.never-default:                     нет
ipv4.may-fail:                          да
ipv4.required-timeout:                  -1 (default)
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-vendor-class-identifier:      --
ipv4.link-local:                        0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-reject-servers:               --
ipv4.auto-route-ext-gw:                 -1 (default)
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.dns:                               --
ipv6.dns-search:                        --
ipv6.dns-options:                       --
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:                         --
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            --
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv6.routing-rules:                     --
ipv6.replace-local-rule:                -1 (default)
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                нет
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   нет
ipv6.never-default:                     нет
ipv6.may-fail:                          да
ipv6.required-timeout:                  -1 (default)
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     default
ipv6.ra-timeout:                        0 (default)
ipv6.mtu:                               автоматически
ipv6.dhcp-duid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                да
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv6.auto-route-ext-gw:                 -1 (default)
ipv6.token:                             --
proxy.method:                           none
proxy.browser-only:                     нет
proxy.pac-url:                          --
proxy.pac-script:                       --
GENERAL.NAME:                           ap-wlp2s0
GENERAL.UUID:                           90ba40d7-fe10-470e-a4fd-cd89357d1c19
GENERAL.DEVICES:                        wlp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp2s0
GENERAL.STATE:                          активировано
GENERAL.DEFAULT:                        нет
GENERAL.DEFAULT6:                       нет
GENERAL.SPEC-OBJECT:                    /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/25
GENERAL.VPN:                            нет
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/8
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/8
GENERAL.ZONE:                           --
GENERAL.MASTER-PATH:                    --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 20600
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::3170:76cc:f5a1:1c6/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024


ipv4.method:                            manual

не раздает интернет для других компьютеров. Нужен "Общий с другими компьютерами"
ipv4.method:                            shared

